# Will transactions work with mongodb aggregation $merge?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I am using a mongodb transaction to update two documents at the same time.One of the documents I would like to update numerous documents at the same time. And I want to use mongodb aggregation to structure the documents in a certain way. Will `$merge` be part of the transaction and update all docs or is there a posibility of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the transaction will not work. According to mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions-operations/#crud-operations) `db.collection.aggregate()` is allowed in transaction but the `$merge` stage is excluded. See more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions-operations/#transactions-operations-crud).