# MongoDB transaction: await a query and use its results to update a document

Tags: mongodb, transactions, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This question is a continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65287132/9953550).

Since according to the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions-operations/#transactions-operations-crud) I cannot use transactions with the `$merge` stage, is it possible to await aggregation results then update or insert documents returned from an aggregation results?

For example

```
// the below operations are all in one transaction

// operation 1 simple update transaction of collection A
// operation 2 aggregation of documents from collection B
// operation 3 using results from transaction 2 to update collection B
```

Comment: What happens if you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a transaction for a single operation. Given the sequence of operations in your question:

```
// transaction 1 simple update transaction of collection A
// transaction 2 aggregation of documents from collection B
// transaction 3 using results from transaction 2 to update collection B
```

... no transaction are needed at all.

Which means probably you can use $merge in a straightforward manner.

If you placed all of the operations into the same transaction, then it would make sense.

Comment: Hey I made the question more clear. I noticed my earlier question had some errors. I wanted the three operations all in one transaction. Is it possible?

Comment: Hey @D. SM kindly checkout the question. I made some clarifications.